# Repopulating an already populated dropdown list in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, bids

I need assistance with something which I have not been able to find through searching this site or even via Google.

I currently have an SSRS report which has a dropdown list that is immediately populated upon loading of the page.

Due to the extensiveness of this list, I have been asked to add another paramater to the report - a text box that would allow the user input and further "filter" the already-populated dropdown list.

By adding this feature, it would allow the user to narrow the contents of the dropdown list, if the user already knows what value he/she is after.

Now this is where I'm getting stuck... as far as I am aware, you can only have one dataset that is able to provide the data of any given paramater (in this case, a dropdown list). So how do you repopulate a dropdown list, that has already been populated?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Please note that the only code driving this report are SQL stored procedures. This report was created using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a second dataset in order to populate your dropdown. In the second dataset, simply take your sql query and select distinct in a group, then you can use the second dataset as the dropdown and tie it to your column that matches.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response Gabriel, however the application that I have used to build this report - Visual Studio 2013 only permits one dataset to populate any given parameter. That I'm aware of at least...

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot of how you are doing it? Im running 2008 and 2010 and I can have as many datasets as needed. Maybe your running a stripped down version of the program maybe?? Oh- Your using SQL SP? I would dump the SP into a table or view then connect the table or view in order to make your datasets. Why would you use a Stored Procedure in order to make a SSRS Report?